# GotFocus event of TextBox is not firing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm using [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209683) developing Universal Windows App. When text box is enabled GotFocus event normally fired. Otherwise when it is disabled I can't detect user interactions with it. Somehow I need to know that user is trying to access the text box and notify him why he can't do so. Also I have tried to use Tapped event - no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disabled textbox won't fire the GotFocus event (or any other events, from what I can see).

Consider setting the IsReadOnly property to true instead of disabling the whole element. Then events will still be able to fire.